# Swift Workaround to a NSGarbageCollection Call?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, gpuimage

NSGarbageCollector was deprecated in OSX 10 when it switched to ARC.

However I have a situation in which ARC is not working properly. I have a GPUImage application which lets me save photos. When I build and run my app, it will take 10-15 images before crashing.

However when I run it in instruments I can go on for a very long time (up to 75 times).

I recalled a similar situation years ago when I ran into a memory issue like this. When we ran it with the instruments on, an extra call to the garbage collector was being called. When we added a forced garbage collection call to our code, we fixed the bug.

Instruments is clearly making an extra gabrage collection call that (probably to save on processing power) is not occuring in regular build mode.

Do you know how I can do a forced garbage collection call or workaround?

Comment: You may be looking for @autoreleasepool, check around for the documentation.

Comment: Great thanks Ill read it now